# Invoke Javascript in webview store app

Tags: c#, javascript, html, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am working on Windows store app using C# & XAML, In my webview I am loading local HTML file, 
and after that I am trying to use JavaScript for Horizontal Scrooling the HTML.

Before that I am trying to fit the HTML height to Windows height. It is nothing happing for me,

My code:

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
      StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("split.html");
      string Filecontent = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
      webView.NavigateToString(Filecontent);
    }
    private async void webView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("JavaScript.js");
        string js = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        webVIew.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { js });
    }
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var h = window.innerHeight, w = window.innerWidth; window.resizeBy(w, h);
```

I don't think so it is a better solution,  But I wondering about this, It is useful If any one have any suggestion for this. 
Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like you're Doing It Very Wrong (tm). Don't mix development paradigms like this, your future co-workers will hate you for it. Use XAML or use HTML. Not both.

Comment: @mattmanser 
I want to Clarify something

Comment: @mattmanser That I am using XAML for design of APP , I have to JavaScript Horizontal Navigation which is not possible using C#. The HTML file is one of the part in my project.
If there is any concern please try to ask me.

Comment: the script needs to be inside the HTML to be invoked. And a method from the script can be invoked. Append the script to the HTML and then give a try.

Comment: What is the problem? Invoking JavaScript or setting the HTML document height? If the height is the problem, maybe you have a CSS problem. If you already know the height of the WebView, try `<div style="height:500px">your content here</div>`, but if you don't, then try putting everything inside a table `<table height="100%"><tr><td>your content here</td></tr></table>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working and I'm doing two things differently:

First, include the javascript inside the HTML, probably within the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"/>
```

Second, you don't need to call "eval". You can call a JavaScript function directly, including multiple parameters if you'd like:

```
string result = webview->InvokeScript("myScriptName", new string[]{ parameterString });
string result = webview->InvokeScript("scriptTwo", new string[]{ param1, param2 });
```

Comment: Right now... I am not working on this app & Still I didn't fix that one. I will try what you suggested & let you know. Thanks...